# Check Some Condition Before Action Load In asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Here Is my action

```
  [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = "AccountExecutive")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var me = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
            var companyContactsViewModel = new ContactsViewModel(me);

            return View(companyContactsViewModel);
        }
```

Now I want to Update Their Password Force Fully and then user can visit Index page

NOw try

```
 public class ProfileRequiredActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
            

        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(context);
        }

        
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
   services.AddMvc(options=> {
                options.Filters.Add<ProfileRequiredActionFilter>();
            })
```

But IN filter I unable Use Usermanager SO i can't get Currnet user details

I also Want to do same thing in Razor page View

Comment: If my answer is helpful,can you mark it?

Comment: throw error : - CS0119 'UserManager<IdentityUser>' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Which line of code has this error,can you share more details about the error?I use `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();`, in my startup.cs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use  UserManager in ActionFilter,you can inject UserManager into it:

```
public class ProfileRequiredActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;    
        public ProfileRequiredActionFilter(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(context);
        }

        
    }
```

In razor page,it doesn't have actionfilter.You can use IAsyncPageFilter,and judge the name of handler method inside it:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
public class CustomPageFilter : IAsyncPageFilter
    {
       
        public async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
        {
           
            if (context.HandlerMethod?.Name == "Update")
            {
                // Running inside a handler method named "Update".
                var svc = context.HttpContext.RequestServices;
                var usermanager = svc.GetService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
            }
        }



        Task IAsyncPageFilter.OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

startup.cs:

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new CustomPageFilter());
            });
```

Comment: Thanks,  It's Useful in Mvc But what about the razor page ?

Comment: I have updated my answer,you can use IAsyncPageFilter.